# Convert lines endings of python scripts when colcon build

Tags: ros, python, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a C++ package created with `ament_cmake`, that also contains some python nodes.
I work in a mixed environment shared between Linux and Windows, where I edit the files on Windows and run ROS2 on Linux. So the end-of-lines of my python files often get replaced by CRLF, and so my python nodes failed to run on my Linux install of ROS2.

How can I convert automatically the EOL when doing `colcon build` ?

I tried to execute `dos2unix` in the CMakeList.txt but this actually does not convert the .py files, even while there is no `dos2unix` error:

```
# Install Python executables
install(PROGRAMS
    scripts/laserscan_adapter.py
    DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

ament_package()

# This runs without error message but the file is not actually changed
execute_process(COMMAND dos2unix /abs/path/to/workspace/install/leg_detector/lib/laserscan_processor/laserscan_adapter.py)

# This fails with dos2unix: No such file or directory, Skipping: not a regular file
execute_process(COMMAND dos2unix /abs/path/to/workspace/install/leg_detector/lib/laserscan_processor/*.py)
```

However the same commands copy-pasted in the terminal works as expected.
I note that `ament_python` packages works no matter the lines ending.

How can I convert the end of lines or call dos2unix automatically when doing `colcon build` ?
Is there a better approach for this conversion ?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385675/convert-lines-endings-of-python-scripts-when-colcon-build/) by [PatoInso](https://answers.ros.org/users/71833/patoinso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2021-09-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-02**:
Colcon is not involved here, it's CMake. So don't restrict yourself to looking for solutions "with Colcon".

A `CMakeLists.txt` is not executed sequentially, it's a tree of dependencies visited in the appropriate order (ie: dependencies first, then dependents).

Your two `execute_process(..)` statements don't specify any dependencies, nor are there any dependents, so I'm not sure they are ever executed (they could be, but I wouldn't know when).

You'll want to lookup documentation on CMake's `execute_process(..)`, specifically the parts about configuring the *targets* they are attached to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoorn put me on the right track: indeed there are several steps in the execution of a CMakeLists.txt and it is not necessary sequential: from the [CMake doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html):

> The execute_process() command [...] run while CMake is processing the project prior to build system generation.

A trick is impired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10000327) SO question is to use the CODE variant of the `install` command, that is run last (or at least after the whole build process):

```
install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND dos2unix laserscan_processor.py WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/${PROJECT_NAME})")
```

The EOL are effectively converted to the Unix format.

---

Originally posted by [PatoInso](https://answers.ros.org/users/71833/patoinso/) with karma: 109 on 2021-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0